# How to load a text with popup (JQuery mobile) from the server?

Tags: jquery, mobile, popup

I'm a beginner. I have a main file with a button. When I press it I want to load a text with popup (jquery mobile) from the server. The text on the server works perfectly, but when I upload it doesn't work. Can someone help me? Thanks.
I want to load this:
...

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>
 
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
  <p>This is a basic popup.</p>
</div>
```

...

and my main page is

```
<button id="btn" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b">Load textPop</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click (function(){
        $("#container").load("textPop.html");
    });
});
</script>

<p id="container"></p>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You forgot the backward slash.

```js
<body>
    <button id="btn" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-b">Load textPop</button>

    <p id="container"></p>
</body>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click (function(){
        $("#container").load("textPop.html");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried the change, but it doesn't work. There seems to be no question of slash because the main program and the textPop.html file are in the same directory on the server. Without slash the download takes place but the popup does not work. This is my problem.

Comment: I just noticed the load method perform something similar to the ajax request for that file, you need a server to do that. I have `live server` installed on my visual studio code. I just open the index file with live server. It works fine when you use a server.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. I also use te server. If I put the textPop.html file directly into the main file, the popup works. But if I call it with the load() function it doesn't work. I tried to change $("#container").load("textPop.html"); with $("#container").load("localhost/textPop.html"); but the result is the same: it doesn't work. I will keep trying. Thank you for the suggestion,

Comment: You don't need to add the `localhost`. You just need to open the main file using any local server. in my case i suggested you use the `live server` extension in visual studio code.

Comment: I already deploy the demo for you on my test server. Here is the link.
[Link to Demo](http://143.198.73.110:7777/cart.ng/test/index.html).

Comment: This is the source code on GitHub gist [Solution Source Code Link](https://gist.github.com/kingzamzon/3ecbe72e6179797b6e62011d3c56c1ab)